# Using JS file for child page in AngularJS SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm building a Single Page Application in AngularJS. This consists of a parent/shell page and child pages within. My first child page is giving me problems - it uses a Signature Pad which it gets from a [JS file](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad), as well as another JS file which I wrote to use the Pad. On the child page loading it must use a function from my file, which resizes the Pad to match the screen size.

However, the child page can't reach the JS file to run that function. The parent page can't reach the Pad to resize it. How do I manage to get the 2 to communicate? Is there a better way to go about this?

My signaturepage.js is the one that manipulates the Signature Pads:

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var canvas1Hidden = document.getElementById("canvas1Hidden");
var canvas2Hidden = document.getElementById("canvas2Hidden");

var createPad = function(canvas){
    canvas.pad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
}

var resizeCanvas = function(canvas) {
    var ratio =  Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
    canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
    canvas.pad.clear(); // otherwise isEmpty() might return incorrect value
}

var clearCanvas = function(canvas){
    canvas.pad.clear();
}

var resizeCanvases = function(){
    resizeCanvas(canvas1);
    resizeCanvas(canvas2);
}

var serializeCanvases = function(){
    canvas1Hidden.value = canvas1.pad.toDataURL();
    canvas2Hidden.value = canvas2.pad.toDataURL();
}

createPad(canvas1);
createPad(canvas2);
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvases);
resizeCanvases();
```

Currently, my JS files are included at either the top or the bottom of the child page - however, this gives a XHMLHttpRequest on main thread is deprecated... warning. This is what I want to avoid. Alternatively, requesting the JS files from within the shell file makes the Signature Pad the wrong size initially - resizeCanvases() is run before the canvases actually exist. It will only make them the right size after the window.resize event happens.

Comment: You must provide some details about your angular app structure, main js and index file for us to understand the problem before coming to a conclusion.

Comment: Sure. I'll post my signaturepage.js and explain some of the other parts.

Comment: have you tried wrapping up your last four function calls into a set time out function. I guess the DOM is not loaded yet. Try 

`$setTimeout(function(){
createPad(canvas1);
createPad(canvas2);
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvases);
resizeCanvases();},0
)`

Comment: Unfortunately that's not reliable if I have to load this page a mild amount of time after the shell. For example, if they navigate back to this page then it will be a problem.

Comment: No It will work if it is loaded after a time from shell to being loaded. More over I cannot understand your project hierarchy with the information given here. Can u provide a proper fiddle of your application. so I can debug it for you.

Comment: I can't really provide a Fiddle - it has 2 HTML pages and uses AJAX loading. Do you want me to pastebin the relevant parts of the code?